# Slope of segment to infinity

Tags: limits

I had a question which came to my mind.

Assuming a segment AB with A (1,1) and B (1,3), so that the line is perpendicular to the x-axis. The general formula for the slope would be

```
(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

So in this case: (3-1)/(1-1) = 2/0 The slope is undefined, but that's beyond the point.

Now, I did a small thought experiment and started "moving" A along the x-axis to the right, leaving its y coordinates and point B untouched.

The new equation becomes: 2/(xa-1)

As xa tends to infinity, the slope grows smaller and smaller until, eventually, at infinity the slope becomes 0.

Now, a line with slope 0 is parallel to the x-axis. However, the original line was perpendicular, and I haven't changed the y-coordinates of either point. For the line to be parallel, A and B should have the same y-value.

Can anybody help me figuring this out please? :)

Comment: The slope of your line arbitrarily reaches $0$, it doesn't mean it reaches $0$. Consequently, you can't conclude the line would be parallel, the line would be very close to being parallel.

Comment: Draw a picture of the line-segment from $(100,1)$ to $(1,3}$ to see that its slope is close to zero.  It is nearly (but not exactly) horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinity is one of those concepts that sort of defies geometric intuition.

If you take the traditional rise/run approach to this:

If you go rise one unit, you have to run "halfway to infinity". But $\infty/2 = \infty$, so going up by one leads you to infinity.

If you rise a half unit, you have to run "a quarter way to infinity". Note that the same problem exists. In fact, if you rise any amount at all, you go infinitely far to the right, so the slope is 0.

If you were to somehow draw this line (I don't know how you'd do it, but good luck!), you would find that it looks parallel to the x-axis. The problem is in thinking of $(\infty,3)$ as a point in the real plane--it isn't. $\infty$ isn't a real number. It is therefore, in that sense, "allowed" to defy our geometric intuition, because it's not a part of geometry itself!

Answer (score 1):

That's the idea of a limit: for any [negative, in this case] value close to zero (but not exactly zero), there is a place very very far to the right such that if A is there, then the slope of the segment is that value, even if no such point can achieve zero slope exactly.

Limits talk about the behavior of a function *around* a point, and nothing about the behavior *at* the point.